# How to disable autorotation for UINavigationController's root view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-interface

I need to support all interface orientation masks in my App. 
Some view controller shouldn't autorotate(it supports Portrait orientation only), but the App still need to support all orientations.
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZgMK.png)

I tried to set `shouldAutorotate = true; supportedInterfaceOrientations = All` in UINavigationController and `shouldAutorotate = false; supportedInterfaceOrientations = Portrait` in root view controller. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in viewControllers that support only Portrait mode

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
            return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every view controller supports a different orientation, you can do this:

1) In the General tab of your project, select the orientations you need your application to support. [for reference click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJIBi.png)

2) Now, add the following code in each view controller:

```
   - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Return whichever orientation you want for that specific view controller in this method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Xcode settings for handling rotation as following steps for that:

Project> Targets> General> Deployment Info> Device Orientation> (check mark) Portrait

Hope this is helpful to you.